# Oscillation of a vertical rod supported by horizontal spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

The system seems to oscillate with $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{3}{2}mgl + 3k a^2}{ml^2}}$ for small angle $\theta$, and in particular for whatever stiffness $k$ chosen relative to gravitational effect.

Is that the correct behavior? Please check my derivation

[image]

For gravity acing on center of mass at $\frac{l}{2}$ along the rod, the height will be $\frac{l}{2}\cos(\theta)$. While for the spring, the displacement $x = a\sin(\theta)$ for $a$ along the rod. Therefore, the potential

$$V = -\frac{1}{2}mg l\cos(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} k a^2 \sin^2(\theta).$$

*Are the signs correct?* Now, using Lagrange method with $T = \frac{ml^2}{6}\dot{\theta}^2$, $L = T - V$, with a small angle approximation

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{L}{d \dot{\theta}} - \frac{L}{d \theta} = \frac{ml^2}{3}\ddot{\theta} - -(\frac{1}{2}mgl \sin(\theta) + 2 \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))=0$$

i.e. for a small angle

$$\frac{ml^2}{3}\ddot{\theta} + (\frac{1}{2}mgl + k a^2) \theta = 0$$

i.e. $\ddot{\theta} + \omega^2 \theta = 0$, with $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{3}{2}mgl + 3k a^2}{ml^2}}$

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: I'll make sure to ask for useful questions in the future, I'll delete my question!

Comment: @Weaam don't worry about deleting it - actually your post got an upvoted answer, so it was evidently useful to someone, and we don't generally delete useful content. Around here, as long as you learn from your mistakes, we don't hold them against you. Everyone takes some time to figure out the system we have. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not physical, so there must be a mistake!

The potential energy is not correct. The negative sign in the gravity term suggests that the lowest potential is at theta=0, whereas this is actually highest potential.

I guess with this change you'll have a transition from positive to negative with oscillation to falling over being the two cases.